# How can I get a special Meta-Data via Wikipedia API?

Tags: api, url, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I whant to grab the KURZBESCHREIBUNG (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilfe:Personendaten) from Wikipadia using the API. What's the correct grabbing URL?

I tried https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=description&titles=Johann%20Sebastian%20Bach but the description is not the KURZBESCHREIBUNG.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
$pageid = 2551;
$url = 'https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&pageids='.$pageid;
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$content = json_decode($content, TRUE);
$content = $content['query']['pages'][$pageid]['revisions'][0]['*'];
$anfang = 'KURZBESCHREIBUNG=';
$ende = '\\n';
if(preg_match('%'.$anfang.'(.*)'.$ende.'%isU', $content, $match)) { $beschreibung_kurz = trim($match[1]); }
```